# Categorized View Displaying the Categorized Twistie without Document

Tags: lotus-notes

I created a view that is categorized, in that view it is displaying the Categorized Twisties without documents under it. Basically it should really not display the document so the twistie must not be displayed too, it is working fine for other items but for a specific one it is displaying. What are the possible causes of this problem? I've been trying to debug and play with it but the codes is working fine and it really should not display.. I would appreciate help.. I know it's simple but I don't know how to solve it sorry, it's consuming too much of my time.. so I asked it here..

Sample
[image: Problem]

Thanks a lot guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a view property called "Don't show empty categories". You find it on the third tab of the view properties in the section "Rows".

Comment: I didn't notice that, thanks a lot torsten,, sorry for asking a simple question.. Thanks a lot